# Find $\operatorname{trace}(BY^{-1})$, given $\mathrm{vec}(Y)=(A\otimes A-I_n)^{-1}\mathrm{vec}(B)$

Tags: linear-algebra, trace, kronecker-product, vectorization

Given diagonal $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, symmetric $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, and $\mathrm{vec}(Y)=(A\otimes A-I_n)^{-1}\mathrm{vec}(B)$, find the following:

\begin{align}
\operatorname{trace}(BY^{-1}).
\end{align}

$A-I>0,$ $B$ is nonsingular.

---

My attempt:

For special case $A=aI_n$:

\begin{align}
\mathrm{vec}(Y)=(A\otimes A-I_n)^{-1}\mathrm{vec}(B)=(aI_n\otimes aI_n-I_n)^{-1}\mathrm{vec}(B)=(a^2-1)^{-1}\mathrm{vec}(B).
\end{align}

Thus

\begin{align}
Y^{-1}=(a^2-1)B^{-1},
\end{align}

and
\begin{align}
\operatorname{trace}(BY^{-1})=\operatorname{trace}((a^2-1)I_n)=n(a^2-1).
\end{align}

For special case $A=\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 &  & \\
 & a_2 & \\
&&a_2
\end{bmatrix}:$

\begin{align}
\operatorname{trace}(BY^{-1})=a_1^2a_2^2 + a_2^2 - 2.
\end{align}

---

```
A=[3 0 0; 0 2 0; 0 0 2];
a=[3 2 2]';
T=zeros(1000,1);
for i=1:1000
    B=rand(3,2);
    [X,K,L] = idare(A,B,zeros(3,3));
    T(i)=a'*X.*inv(X)*a;
end
plot(T)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the vectors
$$\eqalign{
a = {\rm diag}(A),\quad b = {\rm vec}(B),\quad y = {\rm vec}(Y) \\
}$$
and the matrices
$$\eqalign{
A &= {\rm Diag}(a) \\
M &= A\otimes A - I_n\otimes I_n
}$$
Use these to rearrange the given relationship into a matrix equation.
$$\eqalign{
y &= M^{-1}b \\
b &= My = \left(A\otimes A - I_n\otimes I_n\right)y &= {\rm vec}(AYA - Y) \\
B &= AYA - Y \\
BY^{-1} &= AYAY^{-1} - I_n \\
}$$
The function in question is the trace of that last expression.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= {\rm Tr}(BY^{-1}) \\&= {\rm Tr}(AYAY^{-1}) - {\rm Tr}(I_n) \\
 &= YAY^{-1}:A - n \\
 &= {\rm diag}(YAY^{-1}):{\rm diag}(A) - n \\
 &= \left(Y^{-T}\odot Y\right)a:a - n \\
 &= R_Ya:a - n \\
 &= a^TR_Ya - n \\
}$$
The matrix $R_Y$ is known as the *Relative Gain Array* of $Y$ and has some interesting properties.
For example, denoting the all-ones vector by ${\tt1},\,$ it demonstrates Markov-like behavior
$$R_Y{\tt1}={\tt1},\qquad {\tt1}^TR_Y{\tt1}={\tt1}^T{\tt1}=n$$
Re-examining the special case of
$\;\Big(A=\alpha I\iff a=\alpha{\tt1}\Big)\;$ yields
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= (\alpha{\tt1})^TR_Y(\alpha{\tt1}) - n \\ &= \alpha^2n - n \\ \\ 
}$$

---

In the above, the symbol $(\odot)$ denotes the elementwise/Hadamard product

while a colon $(:)$ represents the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB)
}$$
Finally, the diag() function creates a column vector from the main diagonal of the input matrix, while Diag() creates a diagonal matrix from a vector argument.

---

#### Update

I don't think you're interpreting your simulation correctly.

Here is a short snippet Julia/Matlab code which demonstrates that changing  $B$ (while holding $A$ constant) definitely affects the value of $\phi$ and $R_Y$

```
a  = 100*rand(3,1);  A = Diag_(a)
   77.2603   0.0      0.0   
    0.0     83.9703   0.0   
    0.0      0.0     58.4881
     
B  = rand(3,3);  B += B';
y  = inv(kron(A,A)-I)*vec(B);  Y = reshape(y,size(B));
Ry = inv(Y').*Y
   0.564956   2.99807   -2.56303
   2.99807   -0.343684  -1.65439
  -2.56303   -1.65439    5.21742

a'*Ry*a
   18283.48744321049

B  = rand(3,3);  B += B';
y  = inv(kron(A,A)-I)*vec(B);  Y = reshape(y,size(B));
Ry = inv(Y').*Y
3×3 Array{Float64,2}:
   21.8927   17.0631   -37.9558
   17.0631    1.88734  -17.9505
  -37.9558  -17.9505    56.9063

a'*Ry*a
   40704.04750730478
```

Comment: thanks for detailed answer

Comment: Hi greg, in simulation $R_Y$ doesn't depend on $B$ when $A$ is diagonal. Is it possible to express $R_Y$ in terms of diagonal elements of $A$? For my second special case I found that $R_Y(1,1)=\frac{(a_1a_2-1)^2}{(a_1-a_2)^2}$, but for general case I couldn't figure out

Comment: What does your simulation look like? I tried some code of my own (above) and don't see the effect that you claim.

Comment: I fixed diagonal $A$ and for any random $B$ we will get same $a^TR_Ya$, and elements of $A$ are larger than 1. And also $Y$ is solution to DARE, i use the functuon idare(A,B,Q=0). I will include it in my question soon

Comment: I wrote the code from my memory, because my laptop is not with me, but I think should be no bugs.

Comment: I updated my code snippet so that it generates $\,A={\rm Diag}(a)\,$ with diagonal elements greater than one, and the value of $a^TR_Ya$ still changes as $B$ changes.

Comment: can you please my code, I get same value $a^TR_Ya$

Comment: I remember something, I wanted to find $\mathrm{trace}(\hat{B}^TX\hat{B})$, later I found that  $\mathrm{trace}(\hat{B}^TX\hat{B})=\mathrm{trace}(BY^{-1})$, where $\hat{B}\hat{B}^T=B$ and $X=Y^{-1}$. $X$ is the solution to DARE. So what I mean is that if we have fixed diagonal $A$, and we create random $\hat{B}$, and we find $X$ using idare, then $a^TR_Xa$ doesn't depend on $\hat{B}$. Here is the link to my new question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3728954/relative-gain-array

Comment: In your code, $B$ is rectangular; in your question $B$ is symmetric. It cannot be rectangular since $A$ and $I$ are square.  You also need parentheses around the elementwise matrix term $(X.*inv(X))$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109655/discussion-between-lee-and-greg).